# Changing path of ADFv2 Hive logs for HDInsight

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

I have noticed that whenever I run any ADFv2 pipeline (HDInsightHive activity), a container 'adfjobs' is created in the default storage for the cluster if it's not already existing. Also, a folder (call it pseudo folder since it's blob based) HiveQueryJobs appears under that container which in turn seems to be storing logs of various run instances. Can we change this path in an ADF acivity? I haven't seen any such option yet. This would be a good option where lets say one would like to create a more logically meaningful path for log files of each run (e.g. pipelinename/date_id).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot change location of Azure Data Factory job logs.

By default, Azure Data Factory create a folder name "adfjobs" to store the ADF job logs.

The "adflogs" folders saves the log files with meaningful path.

**Example:** I have submitted a mapreduce job and the logs files related to this job is located in the path "`adfjobs / MapReduceJobs / 04e3074c-b641-4a1d-b766-29bc48b41884 / 13_08_2019_05_13_43_619 / Status`" which has meaningful path "`logs folder / Jobtype / RunID / Timestamp / Status of job`".

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: so the adfjobs folder (actually container) will always reside in the default storage for the cluster?

Comment: It will be created once you have run any job for first time. Yes, adfjobs is actually container that resides in the default storage for the cluster created.

Comment: by logical I mean, it could be any logical scheme which would make more sense depending on a project -- say adfjobs/ADFPipelineName/RunId/TimeStamp/Status etc. This is one example, but it could be anything. What I am trying to sense it could be a genuine use case , it would have been good to have this option