# Where to mention a "container" in the storage to store logs when on-demand HDInsight cluster gets created using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight

The hdinsight on demand in ADF is creating a new blob container for every new run.

How can I mention a new container to store those logs ?

It was asked before too but is there an option now [in 2023] ?

[How to avoid hdinsight on demand in azure data factory from creating a new container everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795090/how-to-avoid-hdinsight-on-demand-in-azure-data-factory-from-creating-a-new-conta)

[Changing path of ADFv2 Hive logs for HDInsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815827/changing-path-of-adfv2-hive-logs-for-hdinsight)

For every run of the HDInsight cluster, it creates a new container with the logs.

I want to know if it's possible to specify a container name (and a folder path inside it) to store the logs ? Rather than seeing the logs being developed directly on the main storage account as a new container.